# How to find square root of a number in base $B$?

Tags: number-theory, roots, square-numbers

How to find the square root of a number in base $B$?

For example, the square root of $4$ in base $2$ will be $100^{\frac{1}{2}} = 10$.

Comment: Actually, in base 2 it will be $10$. Being the square (or square root) of another number does not depend on the system to write the numbers - even without a positional system the square root of  IV is II in roman numerals

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Yes I have edited now.

Comment: Do you mean both [square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root), or just the principle one?

Comment: You might find http://johnkerl.org/doc/square-root.html interesting.

Comment: principal one....

Comment: Just do square root in base $10$ and transfer to base $B$.